# Running 2 application which executes own Apache server, side by side

Tags: oracle, apache, localhost, wamp

How to run Oracle [9i or 10G] and WAMP side by side ?  I want to access both of them through `localhost`

But only that app open through the `localhost` which gets started earlier.
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they both run Apache, they will each have an `httpd.conf` file. Change the port number - probably `80` by default - in the `Listen` parameter in one or both configuration files so they don't clash. And if set (i.e. not commented out) set the `ServerName` parameter to match; that might not specify a port number at all, in which case you would have to change it from `localhost` to `localhost:81`, or whatever port number you want to use. Then retstart WAMP services and/or the Oracle Apache server.

For some reason there's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1YaJOYg1tk) showing how to change WAMP.